# Не загружается фото в БД

Tags: php

Пытаюсь загрузить фото в БД с помощью данного кода

```
       <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" 
                                     onchange="document.getElementById('photo').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Загрузить" />
    </form>                     

   <?php
include_once('db.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['userid']))    {
    $sesion_id=$_SESSION['userid'];
    $idf = ($_SESSION['userid']);
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
if(empty($_FILES['file']['size']))  die('Вы не выбрали файл');
if($_FILES['file']['size'] > (5 * 1024 * 1024)) die('Размер файла не должен превышать 5Мб');
$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$arr = array('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');
if(!in_array($imageinfo['mime'],$arr)) echo ('Картинка должна быть формата JPG, GIF или PNG');
 else {

$upload_dir = './public_html'; //имя папки с картинками
$name = $upload_dir.date('YmdHis').basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$mov = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$name);
  if($mov) {

$name = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($name)));
$mysqli->query("UPDATE `user` SET IMAGE='$name' WHERE id='".$sesion_id."'");
  }
  else echo 'Произошла ошибка при загрузке фотографии. Пожалуйста, попробуйте снова';
 }
}
}
?>

    Но в БД, в поле image пусто, ошибок никаких не вылетает, не понимаю в чем дело
```

Comment: Это ваш код? или вам его кто то скинул как пример?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков не мой, пытаюсь подстроить под себя

Comment: //здесь коннект к БД, здесь это где? где он?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков первая строка - include_once('db.php');

Comment: Поверим что оно там и вправду есть, тогда следующий вопрос... Где запрос в БД?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков изменил код в вопросе, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Результат после изменений в студию
if(!$mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET IMAGE='$name' WHERE id='".$sesion_id."'")) {echo $mysqli->error;}else{ echo 'All Ok';};

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков когда жму загрузить, страница будто перезагружается и все, ничего более не происходит. никаких эхо выводов нет

Comment: <?php
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
....
Что выдает?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Array ( [upload] => Загрузить ) Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => 1234.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpbTL3gu [error] => 0 [size] => 353826 ) )

Comment: Тогда что то вы не договариваете =) ибо код что вами приведен - работает =)
Проблема может быть в БД, в скрипте к БД, в настройках сервера =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а почему эхо ничего не выводит? как тогда отследить ошибку

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/Q8H0b297pClXdQ
https://yadi.sk/i/VcYF2rFh4RhzUQ

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков  т.е не происходит коннект к БД?

Comment: Я совсем пропустил одну важную строку =))
<?php print_r($_SESSION);....
Что ответом будет? сами догадаетесь?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков понял, проблема с сессиями, буду смотреть

Comment: `$upload_dir.date('YmdHis')` вернет `/public_html20180919234900`, вряд ли у вас есть такая папка. Похоже забыли слэш добавить в `$upload_dir`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков У меня есть папка public_html, я прописываю такой путь $upload_dir = '/public_html/';  но выдает  move_uploaded_file(/public_html/201809191710141234.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in